# Как сделать циклический ввод в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вообщем довольно нелепая ситуация:
Мне нужно заполнить массив массивами с клавиатуры (список списками), пока не будет введено "end". Мой код не работает, и у меня нет мыслей как это исправить:

```
matrix = []
while input() != 'end':
    try:
        matrix.append([int(k) for k in input().split()])
    except:
        break

print(matrix)
```

Ниже ввод/вывод с этого кода.

Ввод:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8
end
```

Вывод:

```
[[4, 5, 6]]
```

Вывод ожидался такой: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]]`

Отладчиком я пользовался, не помогло прояснить ситуацию

Comment: Не работает бывает разное, какое конкретно в вашем случае - гадать предлагаете? Второе замечание: используйте отладчик, он служит для поиска причин "не работает".

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: программа почему-то в массив записывает только четные строки. Я так понимаю мой первый инпут уходит в проверку условия в цикле while. Как можно это реализовать по другому?

Comment: Какая-то подозрительно знакомая формулировка условия. Ну да ладно. Последний ваш комментарий очень важен для того, чтобы вы поняли, что именно происходит. Обратите внимание на функцию `input()` и на моменты, когда она вызывается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `input()` каждый раз возвращает следующую введеную строку. И поэтому все нечетные строки вы сравниваете с `'end'`, а четные -- заносите в матрицу.

Вам следует сохранять каждую введеную строку в переменную, а затем работать с ней, например, вот так:

```
matrix = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == 'end':
        break
    try:
        matrix.append([int(k) for k in line.split()])
    except:
        break

print(matrix)
```

Comment: спасибо. больше не буду таких глупых вопросов задавать)